# OnDrag JavaScript/JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do a drop and drag and I'm following this tutorial: https://youtu.be/hqSlVvKvvjQ?t=503

but my events are not getting fired. What's the problem?

```js
var dropzone = $('#dropzone');

dropzone.ondragover = function() {
  console.log("entered");
  this.className = 'dropzone dragover';
  return false;
};
dropzone.ondragleave = function() {
  this.className = 'dropzone';
  return false;
};
dropzone.ondrop = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.className = 'dropzone';
  return false;
};
```

```css
.dropzone {
    border: 2px dashed #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 60px;
}
.dropzone p {
    font-size: 25px;
}
.dropzone.dragover {
    border-color: #000;
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropzone" id="dropzone">
  <p>Drag & Drop</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `dropzone` is a jQuery object, because you passed in `$('#dropzone')`. So you would need to use jQuery style events to get this working.

```js
var dropzone = $('#dropzone');

dropzone.on('dragover', function() {
    $(this).addClass('dragover');
    return false;
});

dropzone.on('dragleave', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('dragover');
    return false;
});

dropzone.on('drop', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).removeClass('dragover');
    return false;
});
```

```css
.dropzone {
    border: 2px dashed #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 60px;
}
.dropzone p {
    font-size: 25px;
}
.dropzone.dragover {
    border-color: #000;
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropzone" id="dropzone">
  <p>Drag & Drop</p>
</div>
```

Or other way around, just use vanilla js. For this pass the DOM element to the `dropzone` variable and keep eyerything else like it was in your post.

```js
var dropzone = document.getElementById('dropzone');

dropzone.ondragover = function() {
    this.className = 'dropzone dragover';
    return false;
};

dropzone.ondragleave = function() {
    this.className = 'dropzone';
    return false;
};

dropzone.ondrop = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.className = 'dropzone';
    return false;
};
```

```css
.dropzone {
    border: 2px dashed #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 60px;
}
.dropzone p {
    font-size: 25px;
}
.dropzone.dragover {
    border-color: #000;
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropzone" id="dropzone">
  <p>Drag & Drop</p>
</div>
```

Comment: how do I get the data?

Comment: That's not part of your initial question. So if you have additional questions after the tutorial, please create a new question here on SO and we'll trying to help you! For now your question here should be answered. Thanks @dadasd